# all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification when adding google plya-services

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-support-library

When adding `google play-services` library so I can add in a map I got this error:

> all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

My dependencies are as follows:

```html
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

I tried to change the `android support` version as well as the `android play services` version, but the error remained.

Comment: What is the error?  You shared the dependency but not the error message, as far as I can tell.

Comment: all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a constant version, remove the `+`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'
```

And also avoid adding the whole API, choose only the one that you need, you can find them [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). For example, if you know you will only need Google Maps then just add this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

Instead of the whole thing like you did.

**EDIT:**

Add this to your project build gradle file (not the module one):

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1

Comment: @Halgo which part of the API exactly do you want to use? Google Maps, Google Places, etc.?

Comment: @Halgo Then delete `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'`. And add these two: `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'` and `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'`

Comment: @Halgo Glad I could help! Good luck!

Comment: @ElezabethMathew Great! Good luck :)