# Error: fix the version conflict (google play services) Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

As per this SO thread, I know there are version conflicts, but issue still persists after new versions from Google.

> Error: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 12.0.1.

My **build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
....
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**What changes are required now?**

Comment: Have you added the Google maven URL as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50649458/7915814)?

Comment: If anyone face such error then change play services version to 12.0.1 and add maven in repositories and dont forget to change gms version to 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `implementation` instead of `compile`.

And use this gradle libraries, I already checked in my pc.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.41"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

Also In **Project level** `build.gradle` add repositories:

```
repositories {
maven{
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Check screenshot for better understand:

[image]

Comment: ERROR: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.2.

Comment: Answere edited, check please. just do `com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.2`

Comment: Also tried it stll didnt worked. here is the new error : Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.2
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.2.
Open File
Show Details

Comment: When i clicked install repository it says Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.2"

Comment: You have to add `maven` in `repositories`, check my answere.

Comment: and dont forget to add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` in `Project level -> build.gradle -> in dependencies` if you aren't already added!

Comment: Same error persists. I have added maven just like you said and updated classpath too. it couldnt find dependency

Comment: are you already added: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` in `Project level -> build.gradle -> on dependencies`

Comment: Yes i did. I have rechecked

Comment: add this also: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' `   **check screenshot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Ugx.png

Comment: ok man, I tried my best and provide you all possible solution. thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks. Can i lower the version from 15.0.2 since i read somewhere that 15.0.2 is not available in google play services.?

Comment: It worked actually after changing it to 12.0.1. I think Version 15.0.2 is not available in google-play-services that is why causing errors. thanks for support brother.

Comment: **Great news bro!** then your issue was, you have to add `maven` in `repositories`. Happy coding.

Comment: With the 15.0.0 updates of the Google Play services SDK, there is no longer a `com.google.android.gms:play-services` target (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#april_12_2018_-_version_1500)

This was an alias target which pulls in **all** play-services- and firebase- libraries. Likely not what you want. You should use individual targets instead.